# How can I make a string into a list without keys?

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.3

So a part of my code was doing like so

```
            bag = {'eggs', 'milk', 'youghurt'}
            print(bag.values())
            for x in kaupat:
                if set(kauppat[x]).issuperset(set(bag)) is True:
                    for key in shops[x]:
                        keylist = {key}
                        if set(bag).issuperset(keylist) is True:
                            price+= float(kauppat[x][key])
                            prices[x] = price
```

and it worked while I was writing my code when I had set bag as

```
bag = {'eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'}
```

but now that bag is supposed to be from input, I can't seem to be able to create the kind of dictionary that my current program can use. The input would be something like this:

```
input = "eggs milk yogurt"
```

and I've tried splitting it into a list and using it as is or made a dictionary out of it but it always errors out because the form is not exactly as I had during testing.

So is there any way for me to change string

```
eggs milk yogurt
```

into

```
{'eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'}
```

or do I have to backpedal a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were making a `set`, not a dictionary (`dict`):

```
>>> type({'eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'})
<class 'set'>
```

If you want to make a `set` from a `list` (or anything that looks like one), you can just pass it, like this:

```
>>> set(['eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'])
{'eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'}
```

A `list` is also what `split` returns, so you can do:

```
>>> set('eggs milk yogurt'.split())
{'eggs', 'milk', 'yogurt'}
```

You just have to do this once. Passing a set to `set()` does nothing, so in the rest of your code, you can just write `bag` instead of `set(bag)`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are after a dictionary.  How about:

```
a = "eggs milk yogurt"
b = a.split(" ")
c = dict(zip(range(len(b)),b))
print(c)
{0: 'eggs', 1: 'milk', 2: 'yogurt'}
```